# how to export slack users email as json

Tags: slack-api

I exported slack team users for migrating to another chat server like rocket.chat. and I used the export option in slack but couldn't find the email in the json data?
How can I find the email?
[This is the correct API for slack exported json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJLl7.png)

[this is my exported slack users json data which i couldn't fine the email from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FncxT.png)

Comment: To improve the possibilities to receive an answer you should post the code that you're using, explain better what you expect to receive and finally not using external image link of data structure.
Some hints about good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Slack [users.list API](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list).  It's a JSON API and the method response includes email addresses.

In fact, if you only need to do this once, you can just use the 'tester' page:  https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list/test

Comment: I was trying to see but I couldn't find the correct one

Comment: Did you find what you needed yehualashet and did this work? If so, please accept my answer.

Comment: I Did what you said and I face another problem when I try to import to the Rocket chat, it says you miss  the import class,so what I  am thinking is I  override the user.json file from the zip file so as to import it to the Rocket chat,so what do you think???

Comment: This question is about exporting Slack user emails in JSON format which is the question I answered.  I know nothing about Rocket chat.

If you are having another issue importing into Rocket chat, then you should raise another question.

Answer (score 0):

You can include email field into the export by setting email as public parameter in Slack administration settings: go to https://your_domain.slack.com/admin/settings#display_email_addresses → Email Display → select "Members and guests of <your_domain>, plus people from organizations you’re connected to" → request new export archive. Now your backup (zip archive) will contain users.json file inside, which includes emails field.

P.S. maybe "Members and guests of <your_domain>" option will also achieve that, but I never tested it.